# Query all values from table 1 and only the matching from table 2

Tags: sql, oracle, full-outer-join

I need to built a query in order to display the records from Table A at all time, and from Table B when 2 Columns match.

The Table A holds a list of records, i want to display all the time i.e. a Slot List 1 - 3.

Table B is having a dynamic list of values, those have 1 column (**Table_B_Location_Code**) already assigned with an identifier matching to Table A, but a second column (**Table_B_Slot_ID**) will be updated later.

The best case is, that the Table A content is displayed at all time, and hence the Table B content is having **Table_B_Location_Code** and 
**Table_B_Slot_ID** assigned, let it appear.

Additional, I have in TABLE B a date column. This means, that I want to consider only items from TABLE B, if the date is equal to sysdate (**`to_char(TABLE_B_DATE,'ddmmyyyy') = to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy')`**).

I guess it is an LEFT OUTER JOIN. But I couldn't get it to work.

```
CREATE TABLE Table_A (
    Table_A_ID int,
    Table_A_Location_Code varchar(255),
    Table_A_Slot_ID int
);

CREATE TABLE Table_B (
Table_B_ID int,
Table_B_Location_Code varchar(255),
Table_B_Slot_ID int,
TABLE_B_DATE date);

INSERT INTO Table_A (Table_A_ID,Table_A_Location_Code,Table_A_Slot_ID)
VALUES (1, 'Room1', 1);
INSERT INTO Table_A (Table_A_ID,Table_A_Location_Code,Table_A_Slot_ID)
VALUES (1, 'Room1', 2);
INSERT INTO Table_A (Table_A_ID,Table_A_Location_Code,Table_A_Slot_ID)
VALUES (1, 'Room1', 3);

INSERT INTO Table_B (Table_B_ID,Table_B_Location_Code,Table_B_Slot_ID,TABLE_B_DATE)
VALUES (1, 'Room1', 1, 12-04-2017);
INSERT INTO Table_B (Table_B_ID,Table_B_Location_Code,Table_B_Slot_ID,TABLE_B_DATE)
VALUES (1, 'Room1', 0, 12-01-2017);
INSERT INTO Table_B (Table_B_ID,Table_B_Location_Code,Table_B_Slot_ID,TABLE_B_DATE)
VALUES (1, 'Room1', 0, 12-04-2017);

Select * from Table_A;
Select * from Table_B;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you need a `left join`

```
select  ta.*, tb.Table_B_Slot_ID
from    Table_A ta
left join
        Table_B tb
on      ta.Table_A_ID = tb.Table_B_ID and
        ta.Table_A_Slot_ID = tb.Table_B_Slot_ID
```

If you want to display some value instead of `null` in the rows not matched on table B, you can use coalesce

```
select  ta.*, coalesce(tb.Table_B_Slot_ID, -1)
```

**Edit** (after question was edited)

If you need to only take into account rows of table B with a specific value, the best you can do is adding that condition to the `join` condition

```
select  ta.*, tb.Table_B_Slot_ID
from    Table_A ta
left join
        Table_B tb
on      ta.Table_A_ID = tb.Table_B_ID and
        ta.Table_A_Slot_ID = tb.Table_B_Slot_ID and
        to_char(tb.TABLE_B_DATE,'ddmmyyyy') = to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy')
```

Comment: Almost, but i need to consider a date from TABLE B, i missed that in my first edit.

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Does this helps you: ?

```
Select * from Table_A LEFT JOIN Table_B 
    on Table_A.Table_A_SLOT_ID = Table_B.Table_B_SLOT_ID and 
    TABLE_A.Table_A_Location_Code = Table_B.Table_B_Location_Code and
    to_char(Table_B.Table_B_DATE,'ddmmyyyy') = to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy');
```